# Soft-code ILogger in HostManager and InternalDependencyResolver

Tags: openrasta

I created my own ILogger implementation and register an instance via

```
ResourceSpace.Uses.Resolver.AddDependencyInstance<ILogger>(...)
```

inside the

```
using (OpenRastaConfiguration.Manual)
```

block.

This works fine for most log messages, however some classes in OpenRasta try to figure out their ILogger instance before the DI is ready, like HostManager:

```
static HostManager()
{
    Log = DependencyManager.IsAvailable
        ? DependencyManager.GetService<ILogger>()
        : new TraceSourceLogger();
}
```

In my case (and I suspect the general case), *IsAvailable* is false, so it defaults to *TraceSourceLogger*.

As *static ILogger HostManager.Log* is not a public property, I hacked it and made it public so that I can now set it.

When it comes to *InternalDependencyResolver*, which is always initialized to *new TraceSourceLogger()* on object construction, it does have a publicly settable *ILogger Log* property, so I could just use that.

Now all of OpenRasta's log messages that I've encountered so far go to my custom ILogger.

Does anyone know of a way to get all of OpenRasta's classes (I did not check systematically and might have missed a class or two) to log to a custom ILogger without having to hack the sources? (It's always nice to know that upgrading OpenRasta won't require repatching and rebuilding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you found out, it's an ordering issue. Happy to take a patch to fix that though.

Comment: I wonder if it's worth the effort working on patches for OpenRasta 2.0.x, which I'm currently on (2.0.3). I guess I should start looking at going 2.1. Version 3 is still in the making, if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: Well seeing as 2.0 is not in any code repository anymore i'd say no, all the work is now in the 2.1 branch (the master of each repo).

Comment: I'm working on deploying an OpenRasta service, and am having this issue. I want the OR logs to go to my logging implementation, but it's not working. Is there a way we can do this without building our own fork of OR?